# How can I make this Python code more efficient with a big dataset?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I need to find all call amounts of all the ids from multiple datasets (5 million rows in one dataset). What makes it more challenging and time-consuming for me, is that I have a huge dataset (almost 50 million rows). I've separated it into much smaller parts to go through it quicker.

I am doing it in Jupyter notebook and using Python. This is the code I have at the moment.

The dataset I'm going through has about 5 million rows of data.

```
all_ids_dict = defaultdict(int)
df_dict = smallerData1.to_dict('records')
look_through_ids = []

for row in df_dict[:]:
    caller_id = row["user_id"]
    
    # The dataset has data of calls for different ids and I only want to go through each id once
    if caller_id not in looked_through_ids:
        looked_through_ids.append(caller_id)
        all_calls = (smallerData1.user_id == caller_id).sum()

        if caller_id in all_ids_dict:
            all_ids_dict[caller_id] += all_calls
        else:
            all_ids_dict[caller_id] = all_calls
```

Comment: how many unique ids are in `looked_through_ids`? `caller_id not in looked_through_ids` is O(n), consider making `looked_through_ids` a `set`

Comment: There are about 500 000 unique ids in the whole dataset. I will try making it a set.

Comment: Use a *`set`* instead of a `list` for `look_through_ids = []`